# Implementing a multi parameter generic method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to learn generics, but there is some things I just cant wrap my head around.

Here are the interfaces and classes in play:

```
public interface IQueryExecutor
{
    T ExecuteQuery<T>(IQuery<T> query);

    T ExecuteQuery<T, T1>(IQuery<T, T1> query);        
}

public interface IQuery<out T>
{
    T Execute();        
}

public class StringQuery : IQuery<string>
{
    public string Execute()
    {
        return "String query executed";
    }
}

public interface IQuery<out T, in T1>
{
    T Execute(T1 input);
}

public class ListQuery : IQuery<List<string>, string>
{
    public List<string> Execute(string input)
    {
        return new List<string>() { input };
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to implement the second method in the queryExecutor:

```
public class QueryExecutor : IQueryExecutor
{
    public T ExecuteQuery<T>(IQuery<T> query)
    {
        return query.Execute();
    }

    public T ExecuteQuery<T, T1>(IQuery<T, T1> query)
    {
        return query.Execute(T1 input);
    }        
}
```

I want to pass T1 as parameter to the method implementation, but that is not possible (could be done by using an IoC container like Autofac, but that's not what I want). Help! There must be some very basics of generics I don't understand.

So the question is, how do I implement:

```
public T ExecuteQuery<T, T1>(IQuery<T, T1> query)
{
        return ????
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass this parameter here like this? T ExecuteQuery<T, T1>(IQuery<T, T1> query, T1 parameter);

Comment: What exactly do you expect `query.Execute(T1 input)` to do?

Comment: I dont believe it is a duplicate since the linked question is about syntax?

I have added examples of the query implementations, to clarify what the queries could do.


@MistyK: That is a possible workaround. I tested it and it works. I will accept your answer as a solution if it is not possible to get my original code to work as-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass input parameter somewhere. The best option would be to extend method signature to accept input parameter like this:

```
public interface IQueryExecutor
{
    T ExecuteQuery<T>(IQuery<T> query);

    T ExecuteQuery<T, T1>(IQuery<T, T1> query, T1 input);        
}
```

The second option is to remove a second version of your IQuery interface pass input parameter in constructor.

```
public class ListQuery : IQuery<List<string>>
{
    private string _input;

    public ListQuery(string input)
    {
       _input= input;
    }
    public List<string> Execute()
    {
        return new List<string>() { _input };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! If you change your first solution to take T1 as param I'll mark it as answer (like you did in the original comment).

Comment: My mistake,  fixed